# Why does Internet Explorer fire the window "storage" event on the window that stored the data?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Internet Explorer 10 fires the window "storage" event on the same window that stored to local storage.

It seems like other browsers only fire the event on all other windows, so I don't have to worry about a window that's listening to storage events reacting to its own storing. Why does IE fire the event in the wrong window, and how can I replicate the standard behavior in IE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Microsoft seems to be aware of the issue, but it doesn't look like they're going to fix it any time soon: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/774798/localstorage-event-fired-in-source-window

One option is that you can design your listeners and setters so that they don't react or store when they get information from a storage event that's already consistent with their state. However, this design pattern can be more difficult than relying on the storage event only firing on other windows.

Another option is to make local storage work the same way in IE that it works in other browsers. I came up with an admittedly hacky but functional solution that I tested in IE10 and expect to work in IE8 and IE9. My javascript components don't listen to the window "storage" event directly but instead listen to an 'event dispatcher' I created. The event dispatcher listens to the window "storage" event and triggers a backbone event UNLESS the storage event originated in that window. The way I check if this window stored this value is by using a custom method for calling setItem() that creates a unique ID for the value and keeps track of it, like this:

```
eventDispatcher.set = function(key, value) {
  var storageId = (new Date()).getTime();
  eventDispatcher.idList.push(storageId);
  localStorage.setItem(key, {value: value, id: storageId});
}
```

And my eventDispatcher listens to storage events and triggers an event only if its list of IDs it created doesn't contain this value's ID, like this:

```
$(window).on('storage', dispatchStorageEvent);
function dispatchStorageEvent(event) {
  var newValue = JSON.parse(event.originalEvent.newValue);
  if (eventDispatcher.idList.indexOf(newValue['id']) > -1) {
    return;
  }
  eventDispatcher.trigger("storageEvent:" + event.originalEvent.key, newValue['value']);
}
```

There's a bit more code you can add to keep the idList short and to create it as an empty array in the first place, but I left that out for the sake of clarity. Making an eventDispatcher to handle storage events is a bit of overhead, but it can make your development consistent between browsers. A less hacky solution would use a proper locking and queueing mechanism, but that can be very difficult.

Comment: Do you have a gist by any chance of what your cust event dispatcher looks like?

Comment: Jesse, take a look how it was solved here https://github.com/Shadez/ls-notifier/blob/master/js/notifier.js

Comment: Can you, please, provide more details on it? I really can't get it yet. :\

Answer (score 0):

Explorer fires an event already when it is commiting a new value to a storage. I found that it fires three times in my IE 11 - when old value is null, when new value is null and then whole storing a new value to a storage. My workaround is give listener into setTimeout, I have it with one second and IE doesn't trigger it first time (first window) anymore.