# javascript addEventListener 'storage' in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

What is the equivalent of this **javascript addEventListener**

```
function displayStorageEvent(e) {
    if (e.key == 'storage-event') {
        output.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("storage-event");
    }
}
window.addEventListener("storage", displayStorageEvent, true);
```

to **Jquery?** I have been trying to use it with **.bind()** but it does not know the "storage" keyword. I tried it with this but 'e' is undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    displayStorageEvent();
});
```

thanks.

Comment: How did you use `.bind`?

Comment: Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671852/how-to-bind-to-localstorage-change-event-using-jquery-for-all-browsers

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I did not realize that I overlooked a few information.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").bind("click", function(){
        updateStorageEvent();
        $("#mydiv").html(localStorage.getItem("storage-event"));
    });

    $(window).bind("storage",function(e){
        $("#mydiv").html(localStorage.getItem("storage-event"));
    });

});
```