# Vue.js dynamic element creation with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm completely new to Vue and I can't understand the proper way to render components with dynamic values in Vue.js.

So I have this code below :

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#notes",
    data: {
        title: "",
        body: ""
    },
    methods: {
        add: function() {
            localStorage.setItem($("#title").val(), $("#body").val());
            location.reload(true);
        },
        clear: function() {
            localStorage.clear();
            location.reload(true);
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            this.title = localStorage.key(i);
            this.body = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="notes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Enter title</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="title"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="body">Enter body</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="body"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="add">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width:18rem;" v-for="i in localStorage">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{title}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{body}}</p><a class="card-link" @click="clear">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I can't figure out why does this code renders the elements with the same values, I mean if I have two values in localStorage it renders two elements with the value of the last one on localStorage.

Maybe there's some problem with the loop on created? I need some help with understanding the Vue rendering and fixing my function

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/YegorGunko/pen/vdBjvB?editors=1010)

Thank you very much for spending your precious time with my issue! Thank you for any help!

Comment: [You do not need to mark questions as "SOLVED" via editing the title](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/295637), or [posting updates/thanks in posts](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/109959/295637). Simply add your own answer, and mark as accepted. Anything additional can be perceived as noise for future visitors. See: [Can I answer my own question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @FrankerZ got it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one `title` variable and one `body` variable. It can't store two values in one variable, so the second overwrites the first. You need arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much for help, well, is there any way to use a localStorage object itself?

Comment: You could probably build some behavior around [localStorage changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994774/detect-any-change-in-localstorage). Basically you need to copy the `localStorage` array into an array in your `data`.

Comment: So if localStorage key also matters, then I need to store key and value into two different arrays, am I wrong?

Comment: You could have two arrays, one for each key, or you could have an array of objects where each object has two keys.

Comment: I'm so sorry, can you please review my changes? And I also don't know if it's possible to use .each or something similar to return each array value, not the whole array?(please watch through my code on CodePen to see that I mean) I'm very appreciate your help! And I'm really sorry for troubling you with my personal problems! Thank you very much! https://codepen.io/YegorGunko/pen/vdBjvB?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed my problem based on your answer!

Comment: I'm really sorry for troubling you again but I'm facing another problem. I use object now but after adding the new items to an object and then reading them, function returns just one value. You can see it by adding a note in my app. Any way to fix it? https://codepen.io/YegorGunko/pen/vdBjvB?editors=1010

Comment: Look at the `v-for` [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYBvpa?editors=1010)

Comment: Haha, awesome, I tried something like v-for=&quot;i,e in titles,bodies&quot;. Sorry, so stupid, thank you so much!