# How do I trigger a function when a localstorage variable changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So lets say I have

```
localStorage.setItem('sampleitem','valueone');
```

If a different script changed 'sampleitem' to a different value, how could I call a function when that happens, without just putting said function to call in the script that it gets changed in?

Comment: Use the [`storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) event.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+listen+for+localStorage+changes) of [Detect any change in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22994774/4642212).