# How to look for changes in localStorage in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, observable

I am trying to access the localStorage using Angular 4 and look for changes in the localStorage values using the Observables:

Here's the code I have been working on:

```
userNameObservable: Observable<string>;
userName: String = '';
ngOnInit() {
    this.userNameObservable = Observable.create(
      Observable.of(localStorage.getItem('profileName'))
    );
    this.userNameObservable.subscribe((name: String) => {
      this.userName = name;
    })
}
```

but I am getting an error `ERROR TypeError: this._subscribe is not a function`. How do I resolve this? Is there a better and efficient way to look for changes in localStorage?

Comment: You can listen event listener on 'storage'
Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4689033/5562006

Comment: @ArsenKarapetjan the storage event is getting triggered only once and is not able to detect changes later on

Answer (score 12):

Find below solution.

Add below code in your ngOnInit or AfterViewInit.

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("storage", this._listener, false);
}
```

and declare the below function within the class.

```
private _listener = () => {
   // your logic here
}
```

also remove the listener when you done with listening or ngOnDestroy

```
window.removeEventListener("storage", this._listener, false);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot keep a watch on Local Storage using Subject but we can make use of Subject in order to achieve the goals.

for that we'll have to create a subject,

```
private storageSub = new Subject<string>();
```

also create a observable,

```
public storageSubObs: Observable<any>
```

assign the observable for the Subject,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.storageSubObs = this.storageSub.asObservable();
 }
```

now we have to trigger when the local storage is changed, for that we'll add the code right after the local storage is updated/changed.

```
  localStorage.setItem('item', yourItemData);
  this.storageSub.next('changed');
```

now where we want to know the change status we'll do,

```
this.storageSubObs..subscribe((data:string) => {
   // invokes when the localstorage is changed. 
 })
```

thanks & regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect events from local storage

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
    console.log('event from localstorage')
    // any change/trigger in local storage will be catch here 
});


// for example you clear the local storage  

window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
  if (localStorage.length === 0) {
  console.log('localstorage empty')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use TypeScript getters to achive this.

```
get userName() {
   return localStorage.getItem('profileName');
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but is not able to detect if any changes are done to localStorage values

Comment: if you change the localStorage values manually, of course it will not detect the changed, but the changes on the local storage must done programmatic ally,  in this case it will detect it.

Comment: I tried this with a list of 100 objects, the application ran very slow. its unsafe for larger arrays.

Answer (score -1):

`Observables` won't work as `local storage` can be affected in many ways.

you can attach `host listener` to `local storage` as `Storage interface` emits `storage` event on global objects which it affects.

**something like this**

```
import { KeyboardEvent } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  host: {
    '(document:storage)': 'onStorageChange($event)'
  }
})
export class MyComponent {
  onStorageChange(ev:KeyboardEvent) {
    // do something meaningful with it
    console.log(`Localstorage change/updated!`);
  }
}
```

Comment: `onStorageChange()` function is not even triggering in above script