# make a notification Bar show in other pages even when reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want when I user clicks on a button, the page that will open I want a bar to show and keeps showing for some time even when switching pages?!

can I do it with js or jquery or even ajax and how plz?!

Comment: Do you have access to the code on those other pages? If yes, you could try using [`localStorage`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22923656/4297364) (as long as they are tabs in the same browser window).

Comment: you can't show it during page load of course, because, well, the page hasn't loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using frames for this. When the user clicks a button, open a page that you've created with a frameset. The frameset will have two frames: the bar at the top and the other page taking the rest of the window. You could use some Javascript to hide the bar after some time. The downside of this approach is that the user won't see the other page's URL in the address bar - instead, they'll see the URL for your page with the frameset.