# Updating the react component state when a global variable changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a global variable that will change often. Let's say it is stored in `window.something`. In react I need this change to be reflected in the component as well as in its state.

Example code:

```
class Example extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { something: '1'}
    }


  render() {
     return (
      <div>
      <input value={window.something}
             onChange={event => {this.setState({'something': event.target.value})}} 
      />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However the value gets set only for the first time and there is no change as the variable gets updated.

Comment: Do you want to use the `window.something` value only for the first time?

Comment: What caused the global variable to change?

Comment: Try changing the fat arrow function to normal function.
Because, using 'this' inside fat arrow function does not work as expected and it refers to the outer object

Comment: it should be a `prop`, something like `<MyComponent something={window.something} />` 
Then in your component `const MyComponent = ({something}) => { 
React.useEffect(()=>{
// do something when something changes
return () => {}
,[something]})
...
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be triggered by a change to a storage object. If you have access to the process that triggered the change, then have it call an update to state. If you don't have access, maybe you could poll for the change every so often.

Personally, I just get it from storage on pages that I need it, or add it to state and use that for the rest of the session.

```
componentWillMount = () => {
    const foo = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('foo'));
    const bar = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('bar'));

    if (!isEmpty(foo) && !isEmpty(bar)) {
        this.props.setFoo(foo);
        this.props.setBar(bar);
    } 
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671852/how-to-bind-to-localstorage-change-event-using-jquery-for-all-browsers) is a link explaining how to set an event listener on a browser's localStorage.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
window.something='1234';

  class Example extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { something: window.something}
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <input defaultValue={window.something}
                 value={this.state.something}
                 onChange={event => {this.setState({'something': event.target.value})}}
          />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 approaches in your case:

1. Whenever the global variable change, re-render the Example component. This is a costly operation.
2. Example component should listen for a change in window.something. For that there should be some magic which updates your Example component state when window.something changes. Then the component gets updated smoothly.

I suggest second method and use a store system like Redux to implement that magic.

Comment: Can you provide an example?